# How to configure cloned MOSS 2007 environment?

Tags: configuration

We are undertaking a process of cloning our QA environments to a new environment. Machines and urls will be changed. How we can configure these changes in central admin level in new environment?

For example : current qa urls are **http://petroqa.companyname.com** and VMs are **webqa1,webqa2 and appqa**

Cloned environment will be **http://petroqanew.companyname.com**  and VMs are **newwebqa1,newwebqa2 and newappqa**

Can we do url and server names changes in central admin after the clone is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint does not take kindly to cloning, be it with a disk cloning tool or copying virtual machine drives. The supported approach is to:

1. Create a new farm on your new servers. By "create" I mean install the SharePoint binaries with setup.exe and run the configuration wizard to create the Configuration database and Central Administration site. You do not need to create anything else.
2. Add any custom solutions (.wsp) to the farm (stsadm -o addsolution). Do not deploy them as your web applications don't yet exist (and later when the content databases are restored these will already be deployed).
3. Take a full farm backup of your original farm using either [stsadm -o backup -directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or a 3rd party backup product.
4. Restore the backup to your new farm. At this point you will have the opportunity to change the necessary values to match the new environment.

Comment: Do I need to take separate back for each server and restore them in server wise?

Comment: No, the backup backs up all of the components in the farm. Part of the restore process is to specify where each component will be restored to. So say you have your SSP and Search Index on APPQA, when you do the restore you'll provide the location for SSP and Search Index as NEWAPPQA. If you're using the native tools, I recommend restoring from the Central Administration GUI as you get forms to enter in the information; with stsadm -o restore you need to put it all in the command line and you could miss something.

Comment: Thank you Shufler for your good information. Is there any best articals and blogs that helps to me. One more question. Will this full farm backup everything like physical files, GAC libraries, database files, feature files, etc?

Comment: Oh, right. You'll need to add a step between step 1 and 2 to add the solutions to the new farm so they are available (I've edited my answer to include this step). This part will handle the files in 12\TEMPLATES and the GAC. If you've modified IIS in any way, you'll need to make those same changes on your new servers.

Comment: Shufler, Sorry for bugging you again. Will new site created into IIS under process of Restore? or Do we need create manually?. If manually, Should I create sites before restore or after restore?

Comment: The restore will create an IIS web site (and app pool) just as it would for a new web application. It's not restoring the IIS metadata so if you had performed any manual customization you'll may need to provide this if you need it in your new environment.

Comment: Shufler, One more question. While restoring farm should I choose "New Confifuration" or "Same Configuration"?

Comment: New -- that's the magic that lets you specify the new values. If you pick same, it will attempt to restore to servers and databases that contain the original values which is not desirable in your case.

Comment: What about SSP configuration and content?. Will restore set to same with new environment. Or Do I need create brand new SSP site?

Comment: Again you select new. The restore isn't restoring like (for example) SQL Server does. Instead, it's really just recreating using the settings you provide and the data that was backed up. It's not very clear at all that this is what is happening so your confusion is normal. ;)

Comment: Thanks shufler. I have this thing next week. It is big step to my company and Me. If everything goes smooth. It will be experience to me.

Comment: Shufler, Sorry to bug you again. Our current production environment. we have 2 WFEs (32 bit) and 1 app server(64 bit) and 1 SQL (64 bit). But for new restore environment we are planning for 64 bit server. So Question is will restore works from 32 to 64 bit?

Comment: I would suggest you test it out. I have never personally restored between architectures so I'm not certain. You're not taking the original farm offline (my assumption is you're creating a second, new environment with all the same data) so there's nothing to loose except time.

Comment: You are right. I am not taking original farm offline. creating a second, new environment with all the same data.

Comment: Shufler, Question again. After adding wsps and restored sharepoint.Do we need to do anything with features activation? Old environment has lot of features activation. Will all these comes with restore?